# Leray Hirsch from Bott & Tu

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I had the same [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015373/leray-hirsch-using-kunneth-formula-from-differential-form-in-algebraic-topology). In fact I do not understand the statement

[image: s]

**Confusion 1:** What does it mean by "global cohomology classes $e_1,\ldots, e_r$ on $E$ when restricted generate the the cohomology of the fiber"

A cohomology class in $H^*(E)$ lies in some $H^n(E)$ and and hence is a closed $n$-form. Why are we allowed not to specify the superscript, $*$?

**Confusion 2:** In the linked proof by jdc why can we say that $H^*(F)=\Bbb R \{e_k \}$ what does this even mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Suppose that there is a sequence of cohomology classes $e_i \in H^*(E)$, with $1 \leq i \leq r$; we may take the restriction of these classes to the fiber, $i^* e_i \in H^*(F)$. The demand is that the set $\{i^* e_1, \cdots, i^* e_r\}$ is a vector space basis for the real vector space $H^*(F)$.

It is true that $H^*(F)$ is a graded vector space, but that's not the point here. Each of the classes $e_i$ may as well be chosen each to lie in some specific $H^{k_i}(E)$, and then the claim is that the if $i_1, \cdots, i_r$ is the set of indices for which $k_i = k$, the vector space $H^k(F)$ has a basis given by $\{i^* e_{i_1}, \cdots, i^* e_{i_r}\}$. This is just slightly more cumbersome to state.

2) As far as I can tell he is writing $\Bbb R\{e_k\}$ as shorthand for the set $\Bbb R\{i^*e_1, \cdots, i^*e_r\}$, writing $e_k$ for a generic element of that set of generators.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed what I meant.