# Understanding Leray-Hirsch theorem from Bott and Tu.

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-writing, differential-forms

[image]

What  does the statement actually mean? Could anyone please share some ideas on it? Also how does it follow from Künneth formula? Any help in this regard would be warmly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401528/relating-the-k%c3%bcnneth-formula-to-the-leray-hirsch-theorem?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Leray Hirsch from Bott & Tu](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993253/leray-hirsch-from-bott-tu)

Comment: @MatthewLeingang What is $e_i$ and $i^{\ast} e_i\ $? What is $i$ first of all? Is $e_i$ some form on $E\ $?  If we take any fiber under the projection $\pi : E \longrightarrow M$ then it will be is diffeomorphic to $F.$ Hence if $e_i$ is a form on $E$ then $i^{\ast} e_i$ will be a form on $F.$ Is it what is meant?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang$:$ I don't know how to finish the theorem using Künneth formula. Please provide some idea if you have unless marking my question as duplicate.

Comment: This theorem follows the Künneth formula in the text. KF is proven, but the remark just before the screenshot you clipped says “a *similar* argument shows...” This is the authors' way of saying that it's an exercise for the reader to adapt the proof of KF to Leray-Hirsch—and not that it's a corollary to KF.

Comment: (I might have done that particular exercise 25 years ago, but I'm sorry to say I can't recall the details)